# HTML/CSS/React float:right doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css, user-interface, reactjs

I'm trying to get an arrow icon to display to the right of a particular table cell in a table:

```
...
<td>
  <Box>
    Virtual Tape:
      <Paragraph>
        <Status value="ok"/>
        Running
      </Paragraph>);
    <Next className="next"/>
  </Box>
</td>
...
```

the "next" class is defined like this:

```
.next {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

but it is still displaying under everything else at the bottom of the table cell instead of to the right. Any ideas?

[image: here]

Comment: Add `float:left` for the `Paragraph` tag as well.

Comment: What does `Next` component look like?  Does it pass on its `className` prop?

Comment: @DavinTryon it is defined as "var Next = require('grommet/components/icons/base/Next');"

Comment: What version of grommet are you using?

Comment: @DavinTryon the most recent, 0.5.0

Comment: I don't see a `base` directory in `0.5.0`: https://github.com/grommet/grommet/tree/v0.5.0/src/js/components/icons